# docker-compose: not supporting double curly brackets syntax

Tags: docker, docker-compose

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"
services:
  mycentos:
    image: mycentos
    container_name: '{{.Node.Hostname}}-rh7'
    hostname: '{{.Node.Hostname}}-rh7'
    env_file:
        - docker_run.env
    privileged: true
    cap_add:
        - SYS_PTRACE
        - SYS_ADMIN
    networks:
      - testnet
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 1
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure

networks:
  testnet:
```

Running docker-compose is giving me this error:

```
ERROR: for mycentos-rh7  Cannot create container for service mycentos-rh7: Invalid container name ({{.Node.Hostname}}-rh7), only [a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_.-] are allowed
```

PS I can run the above compose file without errors via "docker stack deploy" so the problem seem to be localized to docker-compose

The reason for wanting to use docker-compose instead of docker stack deploy is testing containers is easier because they stay to localhost and i can grab contianer id to exec into

Answer (score 0):

docker-compose [variable substitution](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#variable-substitution) is not very powerful and in your context there is nothing like `{{.Node.Hostname}}`, but you can override the values in an additional file:

**docker-compose.override.yaml**

```
version: "3"
services:
  mycentos:
    container_name: '${HOSTNAME}-rh7'
    hostname: '${HOSTNAME}-rh7'
```

The environment variable `HOSTNAME` need to be set during start up:

`HOSTNAME=$(hostname) docker-compose -f docker-compose.yaml -f docker-compose.override.yaml up -d`

This should work for your use case.

Comment: hey, thanks for input, but my case is that it needs to be dynamic (actually match hostname of whatever host i am on), so the answer given is not sufficient

Comment: I adapted my answer to make the hostname dynamic, but this requires to set the used env variable during start up. I hope this helps.

Comment: where should i execute the `HOSTNAME=$(hostname) docker-compose -f docker-compose.yaml -f docker-compose.override.yaml up -d`? i assume not by just using powershell?

Answer (score 0):

Using templates is not supported for `container_name`. From [official](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/service_create/) documentation:

> You can use templates for some flags of service create, using the
>   syntax provided by the Go’s text/template package. The supported flags
>   are the following :
>
> --hostname
>
> --mount
>
> --env

---

> PS I can run the above compose file without errors via "docker stack
>   deploy" so the problem seem to be localized to docker-compose

This is because the `container_name` directive is [ignored in that case](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#container_name):

> Note: This option is ignored when deploying a stack in swarm mode with
>   a (version 3) Compose file.

Comment: curly brackets are used for both container_name and hostname in the yml file. docker stack deploy support using curly brackets in the yml file while docker-compose do not

Comment: @ealeon read my answer again. For the `container_name`: `docker stack deploy` does not support it, it **ignores** it! That's why you think it supports it, because it does not give an error, but it also has no effect.